# style list item inside list

Tags: css, html

How to style list item inside list?

HTML code

```
<span class=bbb>
<ul>
    <li>Arhīva izziņas sagatavošana par studiju laiku vai darba stāžu LLU:
        <ul>
            <li>Septiņu dienu laikā - 5.69 EUR / 4.00 LVL</li>
            <li>Vienas dienas laikā - 8.54 EUR / 6.00 LVL</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Akadēmiskās izziņas sagatavošana septiņu dienu laikā (informācija par apgūto studiju programmu, apjomu kredītpunktos, studiju priekšmetiem):
        <ul>
            <li>Ja izziņa nepieciešama par pirmajiem diviem kursiem - 5.69 EUR / 4.00 LVL</li>
            <li>Ja izziņa nepieciešama par visiem kursiem, sākot ar trešo - 9.96 EUR / 7.00 LVL</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Akadēmiskās izziņas sagatavošana, izdrukājot no LLU IS programmas - 2.85 EUR / 2.00 LVL</li>
</ul>
```

CSS code

```
.bbb ul{
list-style-image: url('2.png');
}
.bbb li{
 list-style-image: url('1.png');
}
```

every bullet has the same image, but i want the list items li to have different bullet type of ul

Comment: your issue is with the css specification.  .bbb li vs .bbb ul li

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific in your second CSS selector.
`.bbb li` will apply to *every* `li` element inside a `ul`, no matter if first or second level.

If you change the selector to `.bbb ul li ul li` (very specific - `.bbb ul li` or `.bbb li li` would also work and be less specific), you will be able to change the image only for the nested `li` elements.

Answer (score 0):

List-style-item should be applied to `<ul>` tags, not `<li>`.  If your question is to have different  bullet types for different levels of nesting, your best option is to just give each `<ul>` a class.  You could alternatively do something like `span.bbb > ul` to select only immediate children, but this is not generally a good practice.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image